# drop down menu is hardly staying open

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

This is a frequently addressed problem in SO, but almost 5 of the threads here didn't offer any help. The dropdown menu items are not staying open unless I hover over the initial item many times. I can't locate the problem in a specific class, any help would be appreciated.
Here is the CSS Code:

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
nav ul ul li {
    width: 170px;
    float: none;
    display: block;
}
#navigation_bar a {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
}
#navigation_bar a:hover {
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: color 0.2s;
}
div nav {
    display: block;
}
```

And here is the corresponding HTML code:

```
<div id="navigation_bar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">شركتنا</a></li>
            <li><a href="">الخدمات</a></li>
            <li><a href="">المركز الإعلامي</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="">آخر الأخبار</a></li>
                <li><a href="">معرض الصور</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">التحميلات</a></li>
            <li><a href="">اتصل بنا</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: In this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mq29ac39/ its working fine. or did i miss something?

Comment: @webcodecs try to select something in the drop down menu... it disappears as soon as you move the mouse downwards

Comment: @webcodecs the drop  down menu is appearing fine, but it's not staying open in the first time I hover over the initial navigation item

Comment: @webcodecs exactly that's the problem I'm trying to show

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because there's a bit of a gap between the parent nav and the child dropdown. When you try to hover on the child dropdown and your cursor passes over this gap, you lose the `li:hover` state hence the dropdown hides.

```
nav ul ul {
    ...
    margin-top: 43px;
    ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mq29ac39/1/

Now compare this one with the original `margin-top: 63px`

https://jsfiddle.net/mq29ac39/2/

*I added background a color to give a better visual idea about the gap*

Comment: Still problems with 43px (Firefox), works fine with 40px for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it